# TextAlignment in a Datagrid --> C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Good morning, 
i have a short question.

I have a datagrid bound on a itemsource and now i try to format the alginment propertys of the cells.

```
   <DataGrid x:Name="dgrid"
      Margin="10,13,386,0"
      SelectionMode="Single"
      SelectionUnit="FullRow"
      IsReadOnly="True"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Patient_view, Mode=TwoWay}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding Patient_selected_item, Mode=TwoWay}"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      CanUserAddRows="False"
      TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center"
      Height="645"
      VerticalAlignment="Top"
      HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFF5FAF7"
      VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFF5FAF7"
      FontFamily="Arial">
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left"
                        Header="Name"
                        Binding="{Binding Nachname}"
                        Width="*"
                        CanUserResize="False" />
    <DataGridTextColumn TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left"
                        Header="Vorname"
                        Binding="{Binding Vorname}"
                        Width="*"
                        CanUserResize="False" />
    <DataGridTextColumn TextBlock.TextAlignment="Right"
                        Header="Versichertennr."
                        Binding="{Binding Versichertennummer}"
                        Width="100"
                        CanUserResize="False" />
    <DataGridTextColumn TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left"
                        Header="Status"
                        Binding="{Binding Versichertenstatus}"
                        Width="50"
                        CanUserResize="False" />
    <DataGridTextColumn TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left"
                        Header="IK"
                        Binding="{Binding Kostentraegerlk}"
                        Width="50"
                        CanUserResize="False" />
    <DataGridTextColumn TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left"
                        Header="Geburtsdatum"
                        Binding="{Binding Geburtsdatum, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy\}}"
                        Width="95"
                        CanUserResize="False" />
    <DataGridTextColumn TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left"
                        Header="Strasse"
                        Binding="{Binding StrasseHausnummer}"
                        Width="300"
                        CanUserResize="False" />
    <DataGridTextColumn TextBlock.TextAlignment="Right"
                        Header="PLZ"
                        Binding="{Binding Postleitzahl}"
                        Width="60"
                        CanUserResize="False" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Can someone tell me why the TextBlock.Alignment dosnt work?
And maybe what to do? 
I saw some solutions with a x:Key template, but i cant use x:Key because :

```
The "Key" attribute can only be used on an element taht is contained in "IDictionary".
```

so i cant use them :(

Im a little bit confused and very new to xaml.

Would be nice if someone can help me out :)
Thanks

Comment: You want to align the cell ?

Comment: The Text in the Cell. The Numbers should be aligned to the right and the normal strings to the left. Edit: is there a difference between the Cell alignment and the Text in the Cell allginment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply [`ElementStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.elementstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) on the DataGridTextColumn that has TextBlock and right align that, it would work.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgrid" Margin="10,31,10,-233"    IsReadOnly="True"  
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" Height="627" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFF5FAF7" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFF5FAF7" FontFamily="Arial" >
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                        Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Nachname}"  Width="*" CanUserResize="False"  >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left" Header="Vorname" Binding="{Binding Vorname}"  Width="*" CanUserResize="False"  >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hi, for some reason i always get this error :
The member "Elementstyle" is not recognized or is not accessible.
:(

Edit: Or Nested properties are not supported: DatagridTextColumn.ElementStyle

Comment: It' cant be, you will automatically get DataGridTextColumn.

Comment: Mhmm nope, maybe i need a specific schema or something?
I just copied your code and DatagridTextColumn has zero propertys at my place.

Comment: it works well for me, i have posted the datagrid with two fields

Comment: @user3793935: maybe you used the wrong casing, i.e.
'Elementstyle' instead of 'ElementStyle'?

Comment: Okay, much thx, that worked. 
But im still confused and cant find the thing i did worng.
But what ever ;)
Thx

Comment: @Simon D. uhm no, that was my first thought too. 
But the casing was right.
What ever, problem solved, thanks to Sajeetharan :)

Comment: Oh i found out what i did wrong.
I simply just did the Style stuff after i closed the tag with />.
Whooooops